# Average of Two Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

I'm trying to show the following: $$\frac{1}{2}(x^{T}Ax +y^{T}Ay) \leq x^{T}Ay$$ with A symmetric and $||x||_{2}, ||y||_{2} \leq 1$. I'm not sure if it's true or not and was wondering if anyone had any insight into this? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Take the example of $1\times 1$ matrices: the LHS is $\frac{1}{2}A(x^2+y^2)$ and the RHS is $Axy$ so the inequality is satisfied for $A\le 0$ and the *opposite* inequality is satisfied for $A\ge 0$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop so if A is PSD, then would the opposite inequality hold?

Comment: I don't know, I did not look at this problem yet. All I am pointing at is that you will need some condition like PSD, otherwise you cannot tell anything.

Answer (score 1):

For any symmetric matrix $A$, we have
$$
\frac 12 (x - y)^TA(x - y) = \frac{x^TAx + y^TAy}{2} - x^TAy.
$$
With that, we can conclude that your inequality will hold for all $x,y$ (with norm less than $1$) if and only if $A$ is *negative* semidefinite. If $A$ is positive semidefinite, then the opposite inequality will hold. In other cases, neither inequality holds for all $x,y$ (with norm less than $1$).